# kthread_stop crashes the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to learn spinlocks and kernel threads, and I wrote a small module to test my understanding of the kernel code. The code snippet is :

```
static int kernel_test_thread(void *__unused) {
    int work;
    int x;
    allow_signal(SIGKILL);
    spin_lock(&kernel_test_device_lock);
    while(current->vfork_done == NULL || !kthread_should_stop())
    {
        if(signal_pending( current ))
            break;

        spin_unlock(&kernel_test_device_lock);
        msleep_interruptible(100);
        spin_lock(&kernel_test_device_lock);

        //do some work here
        for(work=0;work<=10000;++work)
        {
            x = work<<1;
        }
    }
    spin_unlock(&kernel_test_device_lock);
    return 0;
}

static int __init start_kernel_test(void) 
{
struct task_struct * ptask;
ptask = kthread_run(kernel_test_thread, NULL, "kernel_test_thread");
if(IS_ERR(ptask))
    return -1;

kernel_test_task = ptask;
return 0;
}

static void stop_kernel_test(void)
{

if(kernel_test_task)
    kthread_stop(kernel_test_task);
kernel_test_task=0;
}

static int __init init_test_kernel(void)
{
int rv;


spin_lock_init(&kernel_test_device_lock);
rv = start_kernel_test();
if(rv)
    return rv;

printk(KERN_INFO "kernel_test: Kernel Test module started\n");
return 0;
}

// Cleanup module
static void __exit cleanup_test_kernel(void)
{
spin_lock_bh(&kernel_test_device_lock);
stop_kernel_test();
spin_unlock_bh(&kernel_test_device_lock);
printk(KERN_INFO "kernel_test: Kernel Test module stopped\n");
}

module_init(init_test_kernel);
module_exit(cleanup_test_kernel);
```

When I try to remove the module, I get the following stack dump in "/var/log/syslog"

```
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162463] BUG: scheduling while atomic:   rmmod/1719/0x00000200
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162470] Modules linked in:  kernel_test(OE-) intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp  kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crc32_pclmul snd_usb_audio lpc_ich snd_usbmidi_lib input_leds joydev hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep ie31200_edac shpchp edac_core 8250_fintek snd_soc_rt5640 snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer dw_dmac snd dw_dmac_core elan_i2c snd_soc_sst_acpi spi_pxa2xx_platform soundcore 8250_dw i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core soc_button_array mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 nouveau i915 mxm_wmi wmi ttm i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper e1000e syscopyarea ptp ahci sysfillrect libahci sysimgblt fb_sys_fops pps_core drm sdhci_acpi video sdhci i2c_hid fjes hid_generic usbhid hid
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162568] CPU: 3 PID: 1719 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G          IOE   4.4.0-22-generic #40
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162572] Hardware name: ADLINK Technology Inc. Express-HL./SHARKBAY, BIOS 1.14 01/01/2013
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162575]  c1ac1967 b70efc6e 00000286 eeebde14 c139dccf e7d44dc0 c1c64dc0 eeebde2c
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162584]  c1090627 c19b6c68 e5343ff0 000006b7 00000200 eeebde68 c17a4518 ffffffff
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162593]  e7d0be00 b70efc6e e7d0be00 00000003 e7d0be00 00000000 c10a4760 e7d44dc0
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162601] Call Trace:
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162615]  [<c139dccf>] dump_stack+0x58/0x79
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162623]  [<c1090627>] __schedule_bug+0x57/0x70
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162630]  [<c17a4518>] __schedule+0x5e8/0x770
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162637]  [<c10a4760>] ? enqueue_task_fair+0x90/0xd40
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162642]  [<c17a46cd>] schedule+0x2d/0x80
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162648]  [<c17a7085>] schedule_timeout+0x185/0x210
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162655]  [<c124c8b1>] ? sysfs_kf_seq_show+0xb1/0x150
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162661]  [<c1095d0d>] ? check_preempt_curr+0x4d/0x90
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162666]  [<c1095d67>] ? ttwu_do_wakeup+0x17/0x110
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162672]  [<c17a4fd2>] wait_for_completion+0x92/0xf0
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162678]  [<c1096c00>] ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162684]  [<c108b771>] kthread_stop+0x41/0xf0
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162691]  [<f06c109b>] cleanup_test_kernel+0x1b/0xf80 [kernel_test]
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162698]  [<c10f4a0c>] SyS_delete_module+0x1ac/0x200
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162704]  [<c11dc7bd>] ? ____fput+0xd/0x10
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162709]  [<c1089a64>] ? task_work_run+0x84/0xa0
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162715]  [<c10030f6>] ? exit_to_usermode_loop+0xb6/0xe0
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162721]  [<c100393d>] do_fast_syscall_32+0x8d/0x150
Jun 15 10:42:31 manik kernel: [  595.162728]  [<c17a8098>] sysenter_past_esp+0x3d/0x61
```

Could you please help me understand what exactly is going on here ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you may call `kthread_should_stop()` in atomic context? Okay, the answer is yes.

Comment: The culprit is `spin_lock_bh()` before `kthread_stop()`.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I believe that is how we should check for whether the thread has been asked to stop executing.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko can you explain why ?

Comment: It's written in your traceback. I was inattentive earlier to notice that. I did go through longer way, i.e. reading the code (kernel core code).

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I am sorry,I would appreciate if you explain your answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spin_lock_bh()` begins *atomic* section, where it is forbidden to call any function which may wait. But `kthread_stop()` *waits* for thread being exited.

Because exiting from *kthread* destroyes thread structure unless someone increments thread's *usage counter* before. When `kthread_stop()` is called, it:

1. Increments usage counter for kthread.
2. Sets "stop" flag for the *kthread*.
3. Waits kthread for finish.
4. Decrements usage counter for kthread.

Such algorithm for `kthread_stop` garantees, that

> Exiting from kthread **after** finding `kthread_should_stop()` being non-zero is always safe.

But if kthread may exit **without** checking `kthread_should_stop()`, *additional actions* should be taken for garantee, that `kthread_stop()` doesn't see kthread being destroyed. Possible way for doing this:

```c
struct task_struct* kernel_test_task;

int module_init(void)
{
    // Create kthread, but don't start it.
    kernel_test_task = kthread_create(...);
    // Increments usage counter.
    get_task_struct(kernel_test_task);
    // Now it is safe to start kthread - exiting from it doesn't destroy its struct.
    wake_up_process(kernel_test_task);
}

void module_cleanup(void)
{
    // While thread may be finished now, its structure is garanteed to be alive.
    kthread_stop(kernel_test_task);
    // This will decrement usage counter, incremented in module_init.
    put_task_struct(kernel_test_task);
    // Now thread is garanteed to be finished, and its struct destroyed.
}
```

Comment: I think I do not really need 'spin_lock_bh' or any other spin lock in the "cleanup_test_kernel" function. If kthread_stop is going to wait for the thread to exit, then I am sure when "kthread_stop" returns the kernel thread is actually exited.

Comment: The only problem is `kthread_stop` can be called when kthread is already exited and destroyed. But in example code no needs to bother with that.

Comment: It still can happen. What if the "kernel_test_thread"  thread receives a signal and exits. Then I will be calling "kthread_stop" on already exited thread. What happens then ?

Comment: If `kthread_stop` is called for thread which already exited and which structure is destroyed, bad things can be happen. I have updated my answer with a way how to avoid this.

Comment: Tsyvarev - I like your answer and therefore have accepted it. Thank you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, you are right but what if kernel_test_task doesn't exit. for any reason, suppose kernel_test_thread exited before calling kthread_stop in module cleanUP. then crash will definetly occur because of two reason. 1st - kernel_stop will use kernel_test_task TID which doesn't exit. 2nd - you have already increment the counter initially thread creation time but decrement doesn't helped here because thread has already been exited.

Comment: @shashankarora: "kernel_stop will use kernel_test_task TID which doesn't exit" - No, `kthread_stop` doesn't use TID for search the thread task. The task pointer is already passed to it. "but decrement doesn't helped here because thread has already been exited" - The purpose of `get_task_struct` is NOT to prevent the thread from exiting. The purpose of that call is to prevent the `task_struct`, corresponding to that thread, from being destroyed.